# Memory footprint of downloading and unzipping a file from S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, stream, zip, bufferedreader

Let's say I have a zipped file stored in S3 I'm looking to read from. I'm curious on what the memory footprint of the following code looks like:

```
public BufferedReader getFile(bucketName, key) {
    S3Object zippedFile = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
    GZIPInputStream gzp = new GZIPInputStream(zippedFile.getObjectContent());
    InputStream isr = InputStreamReader(gzp, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    fileStream = new BufferedReader(isr);
}


BufferedReader zippedFileStream = getFile(bucketName, key);
//do some processing on zippedFileStream
zippedFileStream.close();
```

I'm a little bit unfamiliar with how file pointers/streams work in Java. Given this file I'm looking to unzip is large (on the order of gigabytes), how quickly can I begin processing this file? What I want to do is avoid storing massive amounts of data in memory if possible. Appreciate the help!